# Windows Username Lookup

Tags: python, windows

I have a working script I found that gives the full name of a windows ID.

```
import subprocess
name = subprocess.check_output(
   'net user "%USERNAME%" /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
)
full_name = name.replace(b"Full Name", b"").strip()
print(full_name.decode())
```

I would like to do something like this instead:

```
USERID = "id12345"
name = subprocess.check_output(
   'net user' +USERID '/domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
)
full_name = name.replace(b"Full Name", b"").strip()
print(full_name.decode())
```

But I get this error:

```
'net user' +USERID '/domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
                   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please rephrase from when you said "My intention is to add".

Comment: Basically I want the script to prompt IE 'Enter Username'
You then enter the username you want to lookup and you get the full name response.

Comment: The interpreter tells you exactly where the syntax error occurs. What more do you want ?

Comment: Yes I understand that.  But I am very new to python and I'm not sure how to solve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
'net user ' + USERID + ' /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
```

notice the spaces.

Or do,

```
USERID = "id12345"

cmmd = f'net user {USERID} /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"'

name = subprocess.check_output(
   cmmd, shell=True
)
```